# Search returns wrong date (date -1)

Tags: managed-property, sharepoint-search

I have a very strange problem with the SharePoint search. I have a managed property of type datetime. when i make a search on this property the search returns a good results in term of filtering except for the value of the datetime property wich always returns the real date - 1 day.

Any idea about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It was a while ago, but I have seen this for dates in British Summer Time on a SharePoint server where Windows was configured to not obey daylight savings. This resulted in the indexed datetime - which was a date-only field, and therefore stored as a datetime with 0000 hours - having an hour 'removed' from it. Thus, a date of today would be stored as 2013-08-08 00:00:00, but be indexed as 2013-08-07 23:00:00.

The clue to this was that dates outside of summer time worked correctly.

If you can, check the full value for the date in your managed property, including the time portion.

Answer (score 1):

This post explains the issue and the solution nicely:

http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/09/sharepoint-stores-dates-in-utc-time/

> SharePoint stores its datetime fields in UTC time. If you don’t look
>   at the data from SharePoint through the UI (the UI corrects datetime
>   values according to local time), you need to correct the datetime
>   fields with the UTC offset you have locally.