# Managed Property Search Result DateTime is delayed by 1 day

Tags: search-results, date-time, managed-property, out-of-the-box

I have a managed property that is having problems with date. The field is set to DateOnly. The item always uses Date-1 .

[image]

Here is a similar question, [Search returns wrong date (date -1)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74615/search-returns-wrong-date-date-1) and have a solution if it were to be coded by explicitly adding a +1 day. Are there any workarounds using out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a calculated column to adjust the variance of the date instead of the suggested changing the time zone. I think it is safer to do it this way. If anyone have a better idea, please feel free to suggest answers and I will update this post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Read below, may be a workaround works for you.

What is the work around to resolve this problem?

This can be resolved simply as follows

- Regional settings can be set at web application level, site
  collection or site level
- In order to minimize the effect of changing the regional setting, you
  can create search center at site collection level or at site vel.
- Change the time zone to a zone that is at least 1 hour ahead to the
  time zone where the FAST farm is located. It is fun to analyze the
  queries after changing the time zone. Go ahead and play with it.

Read more here.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sreedharmallangi/archive/2013/06/12/date-time-managed-property-issues-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: Are there any implications in changing the time zone? It does work but I am hesitant to use it as a solution since it is global and could affect other things.